# Cannot add tools:replace="name" to application tag (Sugar Orm application error)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, sugarorm

I've imported a new lib to my proejct. Unfortunetely it is making an error with SugarOrm's lib.

When I try to run my proejct I have the following gradle error:

```
9-42 Error:
Attribute application@name value=(com.orm.SugarApp) from AndroidManifest.xml:47:9-42
is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:47:9-42 value=(com.myproject.application.app.MyApplication).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:name"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:43:5-263:19 to override.
```

I try to add the replace line to my manifest's application tag:

```
<application
    android:name=".app.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    tools:replace="android:name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

However, I got the very same error.

My application class looks like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends SugarApp{


@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}


}
```

I've tried the following:

Invalidage caches, restart, rebuild, clean, reordering gradle lib import

Please help if you can.

**E D I T:**

**Clarification**: I would like to use multidex on Android 4.4 (API 19) with Sugar ORM. Later versions have multidex by default but on 4.4 I have to import it in gradle, and have to make install it inside Application code.

**So basically I have to set my manifest's application to my application class which also handles Sugar ORM's stuff, and the multidex instalaltion.**

And this causes the error.

Versions:

- multidex 1.02
- SugarORM 1.5

Comment: Do you have "`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools`" in your `<manifest` tag ?

Comment: @sunilsunny Yes.

Comment: What happens if you are giving `SugarApp` in `manifest` instead of `MyApplication`. Will it throw `multidex`. ?.Do this `MyApplication` has any other functions other than multidex installation?.

Comment: Also can you try `tools:node="replace"` instead of   `tools:replace="android:name"`

Comment: change the name of your Application name to something else

Comment: Which library + version are you using ? [it is this library](https://satyan.github.io/sugar) ?

Comment: @xiaomi See my edit

Comment: It is weird... Sugar ORM's manifest doesn't contain the application's element... Can you put your app `build.gradle` file so I can try to reproduce the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the generated **manifest file l**ocated at:

```
C:\my_projects_dir\app\src\debug
```

And now everything is fine. Maybe it was an Android Studio bug with re-generation.